# Can I remove the "sudo" necessity in a django project on OSX

Tags: django, macos

I am doing a django project with Sublime Text 2 on OSX-Lion. I have installed virtualenv, so my project is in "/Users/*myname*/Virtualenvs/"

I need to use a 'sudo' for each command (syncdb, runserver), can I change these rules whithout moving my project and is it normal ?

These are parameters after a "sudo python manage.py startproject"

Chmod infos :

```
drwxr-xr-x  17 root  staff     578 10 jul 23:24 Platform
-rw-r--r--   1 root  staff  155648 10 jul 23:24 database.sqlite3
-rw-r--r--   1 root  staff     251 10 jul 23:09 manage.py
```

and in Platform :

```
drwxrwxr-x@  9 Nicolas  staff   306 10 jul 23:13 Templates
-rw-r--r--@  1 Nicolas  staff     0  4 jul 16:53 __init__.py
-rw-r--r--@  1 Nicolas  staff   144  4 jul 16:54 __init__.pyc
-rw-rw-r--@  1 Nicolas  staff   123 10 jul 23:13 admin.py
-rw-r--r--   1 root     staff   321 10 jul 23:24 admin.pyc
-rw-rw-r--@  1 Nicolas  staff  1706 10 jul 23:13 models.py
-rw-r--r--   1 root     staff  2603 10 jul 23:22 models.pyc
-rw-r--r--@  1 Nicolas  staff  5309 10 jul 23:06 settings.py
-rw-r--r--   1 root     staff  3058 10 jul 23:22 settings.pyc
-rw-r--r--@  1 Nicolas  staff   639 10 jul 23:06 urls.py
-rw-r--r--   1 root     staff   784 10 jul 23:24 urls.pyc
-rw-rw-r--@  1 Nicolas  staff  1895 10 jul 23:06 views.py
-rw-r--r--   1 root     staff  2745 10 jul 23:24 views.pyc
-rw-r--r--@  1 Nicolas  staff  1138 10 jul 23:05 wsgi.py
-rw-r--r--   1 root     staff  1047 10 jul 23:24 wsgi.pyc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to change ownership of all the root-owned files to yourself, but otherwise there shouldn't be any need for `sudo` here.

Comment: Thank you ! I had not seen that and now it's ok.